# IServerXMLHTTPRequest on HTTPS

Tags: ssl-certificate, http-status-code-403, serverxmlhttp, msxml3

I am trying to implement a c++ application that will access an HTTPS server using IServerXMLHTTPRequest.

My current code is:

```
    CComPtr<MSXML2::IServerXMLHTTPRequest> xmlHttp;
    HRESULT hr = xmlHttp.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(ServerXMLHTTP));
    hr = xmlHttp->open(_T("POST"),_T("https://someurl.com/somepath"),false);
    hr = xmlHttp->setTimeouts( 100000,
            50000,
            100000,
            100000
            );
    hr = xmlHttp->setOption(SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT, 
                            xmlHttp->getOption(SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT));
    hr = xmlHttp->setRequestHeader(_T("Content-Type"),_T("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    sPostData = ...;
    hr = xmlHttp->send((BSTR)sPostData);
```

When I try to run the above code, the server returns an 403 (Forbidden) error.

What could be the cause of this? And, what should I do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working!

For those who might encounter this same problem in the future, you can solve this by specifying in the URL the actual file name and extension instead of just specifying the path.

You can refer to this link: [403 ERROR](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/403error.htm)

Thank you!